# SQLServer cannot find my user defined function function in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

I must have some permissions wrong, but I can't figure out how. The following code is simplified but I can't even get this to work

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufTest 
(
    @myParm int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result int

    SELECT @Result = @myParm + 1

    RETURN @Result
END
GO
```

Then I just want to be able to call the function from a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[uspGetGroupProfileService]
@id        int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @otherId int;
    SET @otherId = dbo.ufTest(@id);
END
```

SQLServer keeps telling me that it can't find `dbo.ufTest`. It shows up under [DB]\Programmability\Functions\Scalar-valued Functions but I can't figure out how to use it.

Anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

As indicated by the selected answer below, you can't always trust the SSMS Intellisense. One thing that you can try, other than just trying to execute the script, is forcing an Intellisense refresh with CTRL + SHIFT + R

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/07/04/sql-server-how-to-refresh-ssms-intellisense-cache-to-update-schema-changes/

Comment: Are you sure it is being created in the `dbo` schema? It will get put into whatever your default schema is.

Comment: What happens when you attempt to run the code from the SP by itself as a batch (with a hardcoded value or whatever)?

Comment: The stored proc runs just fine. I just have some code in a lot of different stored procs that I want to move to a function. This should really not be this hard. I'm beginning to think it's something wrong with the install

Comment: +1 ~bump~  just having this problem myself in SQLServer 2005.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Works for me.

Try `CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufTest ...`

I assume your default schema can't be `dbo` and it's ending up in a different schema. Otherwise the only explanation I can think of is you might need to grant permissions on it.

Comment: +1: Works on 2005 for me too.  If the procedure is created in a different database, the function will need three name notation to be referenced properly.

Comment: No dice. If you notice the end of my original post. It is showing up under the proper database in Management Studio.

Comment: Can you right click the scalar function in SSMS under the account you use to create these objects, choose "script function as select to..." Fill in the parameter value and execute it standalone? If yes can you execute it from the stored procedure in SSMS under that same account? If Yes and the problem is in your application you will need to do `GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[ufTest]` TO `[username]` also you aren't just going off what intellisense claims?

Comment: @Martin Thank You!! It worked all along. It was SSMS screwing me up. It underlined the call to the function saying that it couldn't find it, so I never bothered actually trying to run it.

Comment: @Martin Repost your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the solution.

Comment: @Martin I just realized that this was your answer. LOL I was a little frazzled from this problem that didn't make any sense. Thanks again for walking me through it.

Comment: Stupid SSMS. I spent last 30 mins trying to figure out the same thing. Never bothered to run the function even once. (Maybe I am stupid). But, thanks to this answer and comments.

Answer (score 3):

Script out the UDF and check the schema name. It's probably not dbo. I would change the UDF definition to specifically include dbo. In other words:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufTest
```

Comment: It was created as dbo.ufTest, but I did try adding it and still no dice.

Comment: dbo = DataBaseOwner
UDF = User Defined Functions

Answer (score 3):

Had the exact same problem and mine got fixed by simply restarting SQL Server Management Studio.

Just posting this in case anyone else did everything right and is still not able to call his function.

Answer (score 2):

I just had an issue where this was the error and all of the advice on this column was failing as well.

Be sure double check your function declaration type and usage of that type.

I declared a return-type table and tried to call it with `Select functionName()` where I needed to use `SELECT * FROM functionName()`

Answer (score 1):

As a *last* resort if any of the above and especially @jrdev22's answer did not help you (and left you stumped why), restart the SQL Server **service** in [Configuration Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager) since restarting the SSMS alone sometimes does not reset everything (e.g. similar to when creating a new login instance but not being able to login with it).

```
SQL Server Configuration Manager> SQL Server Services > SQL Server > Restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling it with a select instead of a set.  And you checked that out belongs to the dbo schema?

Comment: Tried the select trick too, but that's really only appropriate if you're returning a Table

Comment: Or when assigning multiple values at once or when u using a where clause or when inside a function called ufTest ;)    But that aside it does handle null values differently which your case is using so was worth a shot.  You got a crazy non replicable issue there, best of luck!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by assigning multiple values? Multiple out arguments? Actually it turned out that it was just SSMS giving a false error in the query editor, so I never actually tried to run it.

Comment: Just talking about comma separated assignments; you can't do it with set nothing big.  I am glad you got your issue figured out.

Answer (score 0):

It appears it might be a bug in the query editor. The Function appears in the tree in the right place but even naming the function dbo.xxxxxx the function doesn't appear in the query editor until you close and open a new session, then it appears if you type in dbo.

If you change the name of the function the old non existing fuction is avalable but not the new name.  Refresh doesn't fix this only closing the session and starting a new one.

Why I say this might be a bug is that the permissions properties for Table function includeds a blue link to the schema properties but the Scalar functions it doesn't.  So it may be a deeper lying bug in the way the schema is set up in the first place for which there may be a work around.  Or maybe the schema in the database I am working on has not been set up correctly.

Hopefully someone else can shine some light on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to find the function that you have just created there are two reasons for it.

1. you are using the wrong function name you need to add dbo.function name to get it.
2. I've also found one more issue like even though correct name is entered and also it is existing in the object explorer after refreshing you are unable to find it when you are trying to use the function.

In this case simply close the sql server and reopen it and you should be able to see the function.