# I created a SQL Server function. Now I can't find it in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I wrote a CREATE FUNCTION script, and created a function.  But I can't find it in the LONG list of functions under the programability folder in SSMS.  Where did SQL Server put my function.  It's not in any of the folders, or if it is, I missed it.  And I looked twice.

I did specify at the beginning of my script:

```
USE myDatabase
GO
```

before starting the

```
CREATE FUNCTION...
```

... in the script, so it shouldn't have gotten lost in the master database.

Comment: When searching your function on the "Programmability" folder of your database, did you click "Refresh"?

Comment: `select * from sys.all_objects where [name] = 'myFunction';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look under \Programmability\Functions. To use those objects refer to this post [SQLServer cannot find my user defined function function in stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697241/sqlserver-cannot-find-my-user-defined-function-function-in-stored-procedure)

Comment: Asajj.  You have exactly one reputation point.  Let me just help you with that!  Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

I apologise.  The questioner is an idiot.

All that I needed to do was right click on the Function folder in SSMS and choose "Refresh".

Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your FUNC exists in that list

```
 USE[MASTER]
    select Name, Definition, type_desc FROM sys.sql_modules sm 
    INNER JOIN sys.objects so ON sm.object_id=so.object_id
    where type_desc like '%func%'
```

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS, try using the Object Explorer Details window (under the View menu) to list your scalar-valued (or whatever kind of) functions, where you can sort by Created in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has already been answered and all it needed was a refresh but I recently encountered the identical symptoms and the reason was because I was logged in as a user that did not have permission to see that function. Get the DB owner to grant the right permissions (execute permission) and you should be able to see it.